# What encoding this possibly can be? b2fb1d6c-567d-4d93-89cc-962bc67c6ec9

Tags: encode

I have a base64 string (proabbaly) which convert to b2fb1d6c-567d-4d93-89cc-962bc67c6ec9
I believe this is related with an email id - how can i decode this?

Comment: it looks like a GUID to me. What it relates to is anybody's guess. There is nothing to decode. It's a value.

Comment: UUIDs, particularly version 4 UUIDs like this one, aren't decodeable. They don't contain any information about whatever they identify; that information has to be maintained separately.

Comment: Other UUID versions contain some information about the circumstances under which they were generated (but not the purpose they were generated for). A version 4 UUID is mostly just random numbers.